# Can not understand working of a line

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I took few help online to complete my task. And I found this code but I do not know the actual working as I have never used such syntax before in c++. The (?) Question mark and (:) colon.Can any one provide a simple general syntax code explaining same line?

```
x = (i-coins[j] >= 0)? table[i - coins[j]][j]: 0;
```

Comment: if(i-coins[j]>=0)

Comment: (The Conditional (or Ternary) Operator)[http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/1AUq5Di1/ ]  " The ?: operator returns one of two values depending on the result of an expression.
 : "

Comment: If searching the web for smth. like *"c++ what does the question mark mean"* did not lead you to an answer you need a better search engine.

Answer (score 2):

This means

```
if (i-coins[j] >= 0)
    x = table[i - coins[j]][j];
else
    x = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called ternary operator, and it is used in place for a short if-else statement.

```
int factorial(int number) {
  if (number < 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return number*(number-1);
  }
}
```

The above function can be summed up using a ternary operator:

```
int factorial(int number) {
  return (number < 1) ? 1 : number*(number-1);
}
```